# Arduino Error all of overloaded ‘println(long unsigned int (&)())’ is ambiguous

Tags: c, arduino

Here is my code

```
#include<SPI.h>
#include<Ethernet.h>

byte mac[]={0xAA, 0xAB, 0xAC,0xAD, 0xAE, 0xAF};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 86);
EthernetClient client;
byte server[]={192, 168, 1, 61};

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
}

void loop()
{
  if(client.connect(server, 80))
  {
    client.println("GET /ardunio/ardComm.php?param=ping");
    client.println();
   client.stop();
  }
  Serial.println(millis);
}
```

Here is the error

Serverping.ino: In function ‘void loop()’:
Serverping.ino:24:24: error: call of overloaded ‘println(long unsigned int (&)())’ is ambiguous
Serverping.ino:24:24: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Stream.h:26:0,
                 from /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.h:28,
                 from /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Arduino.h:193,
                 from /usr/share/arduino/libraries/SPI/SPI.h:15,
                 from Serverping.ino:1:
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.h:70:12: note: size_t Print::println(char) 
     size_t println(char);
            ^
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.h:70:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘long unsigned int()’ to ‘char’
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.h:71:12: note: size_t Print::println(unsigned char, int) 
     size_t println(unsigned char, int = DEC);
            ^
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.h:71:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘long unsigned int()’ to ‘unsigned char’
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.h:72:12: note: size_t Print::println(int, int) 
     size_t println(int, int = DEC);
            ^
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.h:72:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘long unsigned int()’ to ‘int’
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.h:73:12: note: size_t Print::println(unsigned int, int) 
     size_t println(unsigned int, int = DEC);
            ^
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.h:73:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘long unsigned int()’ to ‘unsigned int’
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.h:74:12: note: size_t Print::println(long int, int) 
     size_t println(long, int = DEC);
            ^
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.h:74:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘long unsigned int()’ to ‘long int’
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.h:75:12: note: size_t Print::println(long unsigned int, int) 
     size_t println(unsigned long, int = DEC);
            ^
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/Print.h:75:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘long unsigned int()’ to ‘long unsigned int’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`millis` is a function. If you want the result of calling it then you need to call it.

```
Serial.println(millis());
```